# Is there something in SQL/Oracle to estimate program execution time before program execution?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, execution-time

I am a beginner to SQL/Oracle programming. Just like aggregate function count can be used to find no. of records in the result set, I need to understand why some join queries take a huge time for execution.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server, Oracle, or both?

Comment: Performance of queries and understanding why it is less than optimal is a MASSIVE topic. There are literally series of books written on the topic. And the solutions are very different in Oracle and SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not tell you how long, but looking at the Query Plan will give you a good idea why the query takes a long time. Look especially for table scans on larger tables.

For Sql Server, SSMS will allow you to generate the expected query plan without actually running query, or to run the query and show the results along with the actual Query Plan used. Toad for Oracle has similar functionality.

A Query Plan shows how it accesses individual tables, and how it makes the joins between them, along with a measurement of the 'cost' of each operation. Higher costs take longer to run. A full tutorial on Query Plans is a bit more than is possible in this format.

Comment: I would only add that if you really want to learn, that you attempt to complete some sort of course on SQL best practices/optimization or at least read/consult a book on it. Query plans help, but can often be cryptic or don't tell the whole story or guide you to the proper solution. "Database normalization" is also something to read up on if you're new to SQL, although it's important to note that the best solution (for speed and ease of access) is rarely the most normalized solution.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can check the view v$session_longops to see the progress of long-running queries.